# Quickly clone a database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For testing purposes, I often have to clone databases (onto the same server). Currently I do this by creating a backup and restoring it as a new database.

I would love to have such a functionality available as a simple right-click in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS): right-click a database, choose "Clone" and be done.

Unfortunately I found no such or a similar function in SSMS.

**My question:**

Does such a "quick clone" function exist or could I implement one by myself (or maybe through some add-in?)

**Update 1:**

I've found a SO question and answer on using the [Copy wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp).

This looks promising but takes a *lot* of wizard steps. Maybe it is possible to do this whole thing with a single click?

Comment: Just use a T-SQL Script in a SQL Agent job. Right-click the job and select run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a look at my ssms. Copy is in SSMS 2012 and 2014 under tasks. I haven't tried it but it is there. What ssms are you using?

SSMS 64 bit: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-A1533227CD69/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: Better starting points: [2012 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351) | [2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Answer (score 1):

What about an ssis package? Create an SP that calls an ssis package which copies (clones) a db given two parameters; source db and destination db.